# Empty UITableView not bouncing when loaded from a nib

Tags: ios, uitableview

A UITableView should bounce (even when empty) when user scrolls as long as the `bounces` and `alwaysBounceVertical` properties are set to YES. When I initialize a UITableViewController, everything works as expected. When I initialized a UIViewController loaded from a nib with a simple view hierarchy: a top level UIView with a single UITableView child, then the table view doesn't bounce anymore. Here is the code I used:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *rootViewController = nil;
    UITableView *tableView;
    BOOL loadFromNib = NO;
    if (loadFromNib)
    {
        rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        tableView = [rootViewController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        rootViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView = (UITableView *)rootViewController.view;
    }
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    NSLog(@"%@ bounces: %@", tableView.class, tableView.bounces ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"%@ alwaysBounceVertical: %@", tableView.class, tableView.alwaysBounceVertical ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

@end
```

When I run this code with the `loadFromNib` variable set to YES or NO, it always logs this:

```
UITableView bounces: YES
UITableView alwaysBounceVertical: YES
```

But when I load it from the nib (i.e. `loadFromNib` is set to YES), the table view doesn’t bounce when I try to scroll. Why doesn’t it bounce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot precisely explain why, but the behaviour with empty table views seems pretty erratic. Anyway, setting `tableView.bounces = YES` manually (e.g. in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the view controller the table view belongs to) fixes such issues and ensures that your table view always bounces, even when empty.

Comment: yet another reason why you should never use nibs.

Comment: @HeathBorders Which other reasons are there?

Comment: The can't be diffed or merged since the xib format is undocumented XML. You can't see what custom views look like because there are no plugins. You can't use custom container view controllers. I'm sure there are others