# Is using nibs to construct views good practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, nib

I just read a comment saying something like

> Yet another reason never to use nibs

Is it such bad practice to use nibs to construct your views in iOS? I think it's a fine system, enables you to construct views quickly without writing a lot of code. I've been working with nibs for a while now and never saw much downsides to their use.

So my question is: should I use nibs or code my views, and why?

Comment: Where did you see this? Is it vs `xib`s perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316055/empty-uitableview-not-bouncing-when-loaded-from-a-nib/12316255#12316255

Comment: No, somebody had a problem with empty tableviews not bouncing, and that comment was underneath the answer. I never questioned the value of nibs but it made me wonder if there are real downsides.

Comment: Just use whatever you feel comfortable with. Ignore any speed advantage statements as those are irrelevant.

Comment: I never use NIBs because of storyboards. Plain and simple, storyboards are amazing for sketching your UI out, and they allow non-coders to see the flow of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the statement "never to use nibs" is ridiculous. You just have to know when to use them and when to avoid them. They're great for complex but static views, where you would waste a lot of time getting the coordinates and sizes right. For dynamic GUIs of course you should use code instead.

However, some people might fear that the GUI is out of their control, if they don't create it themselves by code and see every detail. But that's a subjective point.

One sure downside is, that xibs are hard to merge if you use **source control**. Xib files are actually XML files and when you change something in the GUI, a lot of references are added, removed or changed in the background. This will then result in conflicts that are very difficult to resolve.

Another one might be **performance reasons**. Loading your GUI from a nib file is slightly slower (in some cases) then creating it directly in code. Some people suggest not to use any nibs for the GUI that has to be loaded at application launch to shorten the launch time. But I'm not sure if there is a significant difference or not.

Comment: I agree. About performance though, are nibs read at runtime? Doesn't the compiler convert them to machine code or something?

Comment: Did you measure this theory or where do you get the information that XIBs would be slower than manually instantiated interfaces?

Comment: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html

Comment: @JeroenMoons No, nibs aren't compiled to "machine code or something". They're data files that contain serialized objects which are deserialized when the nib is loaded at run time.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using NIBs wherever possible!
My reasons are:

- Easy to maintain and in need of a change I can view the result right away.
- Now that IPhone5 has a new resolution - things were really easy to do in the NIB
- Easy to use
- Less code to write

I even make SMALL popup views there and set the container view to hidden.
then I show/hide these popup views with containerView.hidden = YES/NO;